# Power Bi Button to call Python script?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I'm not sure if I really need to brush up my Google-fu skills or if this is actually impossible... but I'm going to ask here to try and save myself a bit of a headache.

Is it possible to call custom Python scripts from Power Bi via button clicks or any other user triggered event?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also curious if this is possible. I am new to Power Bi and Python and I was looking at how I can make dashboards more user friendly with the addition of buttons.